# Cosh and Sinh in the Wave equation.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation, linear-pde

So im trying to solve an equation
$$
u_{xx}+4u_{tt}=0, \ \ \ \ \ 0<x < \pi, \ \ \ \ 0 < t < 2
$$
$$
u(0,y)=u(\pi,t)=0, \ \ \ \ \ 0 \le t \le 2
$$
After seperation of variables i get that:
$$
G(t)=c_1 e^{\sqrt{\frac{k}{4}}t}+c_1 e^{-\sqrt{\frac{k}{4}}t}
$$
When i look at what the answer should be it says
$$
G(t)=A_n \cosh(\frac{n}{2}t)+ B_n \sinh(\frac{n}{2}t)
$$
I have no errors in my speration of variables i think, so no need to write all of that. And i also have correct $k = -n^2$ for $n = 1,2,3...$. So im Wondering about how I can get it on that other form from what i origonaly got.

Answer should also be [here](https://www.math.ntnu.no/emner/TMA4135/2009h/eksamen/lfTMA41xx4ND-10k.pdf), Problem number 3a.

Comment: Your equation is not a wave type equation though. It's elliptic.

Comment: Okay but how does that make it Cosh and Sinh?

Comment: The functions $\cosh(x)$ and $\sinh(x)$ can be expressed in terms of $e^x$ and $e^{-x}$, and vice versa. If only you had $k = n^2$ (instead of $k = -n^2$), this would make the two forms equivalent.

Comment: You should have $-k/4$ in the radical. Can you show your derivation?

Comment: if you write "4y'' - n^2y = 0" into wolfram you get the same as me. As i said there should be no errors in the variable sperations. So im woundering how they go from my G(t) to theirs or just get to the correct G(t) from scratch

Comment: Putting that into Wolfram does not give the same answer as you, so there was an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general,

$$e^{x}=\cosh x+\sinh x\quad\text{ and }\quad e^{-x}=\cosh x-\sinh x$$

We have $G''+\frac k4G=0$. Suppose the solution is of the form $e^{\gamma t}$. Then $e^{\gamma t}(\gamma^2+\frac k4)=0$. Therefore, $\gamma=\pm\sqrt{-\frac k4}$.

Therefore, $G(t)=c_1e^{\sqrt{-\frac k4}t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\frac k4}t}$

From here, we get

\begin{align*}
c_1e^{\sqrt{-\frac k4}t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{-\frac k4}t}&=c_1e^{\sqrt{\frac {n^2}4}t}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{\frac {n^2}4}t}\\
&=c_1e^{\frac {n}2t}+c_2e^{-\frac {n}2t}\\
&=c_1\left(\cosh\frac n2 t+\sinh\frac n2 t\right)+c_2\left(\cosh\frac n2 t-\sinh\frac n2 t\right)\\
&=C_1\cosh\frac n2 t+C_2\sinh\frac n2 t.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!